# How to get multiple Action Hooks in an Array

Tags: customization, plugins, actions

Hi I am writing a small plug-in which I get some content from outside of WordPress and I want a small script to trigger whenever a new post, page or comment is added. Also if any Widgets, themes and Plug-ins are Activated or De-Activated.

My guess is that I should be using the action hooks for this but since there are multiple actions so how to get all those actions in some array or so.

```
class getStatic {

    var $_renderTasksOn =
        array(

              <!-- How do I call those actions in an array here -->

        )

function gerStatic() {

    <!-- Here goes the script to get external data -->
}

}
```

I am very new to programming hence kindly help with the code. How do I use those action hooks?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hook into multiple actions, you have to call `add_action` multiple times. However, this is not so hard. Let's take your plugin class as an example:

```
class WPSE6526_getStatic // Always prefix your plugin with something unique, like your name. Here I used the question number
{
    var $_renderTasksOn = array( 'wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_comment', ... );

    function WPSE6526_getStatic()
    {
        // The constructor of this class, which will hook up everything
        // This is the 'trick' to this question: a loop on your list and `add_action` for each item
        foreach ( $this->_renderTasksOn as $hookname ) {
            add_action( $hookname, array( &$this, 'getStatic' ) );
        }
    }

    function getStatic()
    {
        // Your code
    }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse6526_getStatic_init' );
function wpse6526_getStatic_init()
{
    $GLOBALS['wpse6526_getStatic_instance'] = new WPSE6526_getStatic();
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Jan. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks once again for helping. You really saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Vikram: I'm glad I could help, and welcome to this site! I hope to see more good questions and answers from you here in the future.